# How to convert a CvMat from type CV_AA to CV_32F

Tags: c, opencv

The CvMat type 16 corresponds to "CV_AA".  Is there an easy conversion between this and the type CV_32F?

Something in the same vein as `cvCvtColor(cimg,gimg,CV_BGR2GRAY);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CV_AA` is used for telling drawing functions (i.e., `line`, `circle`, fonts, etc) to perform anti-aliased drawing; I don't believe it is a proper `Mat` data-type. As you can see in [core_c.h](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h), it is defined in the drawing functions section.

Could you show the code where you are receiving this data-type from?

**EDIT :** I think I see what's going on :)

Given that `CV_8U` is this:

```
#define CV_8U   0
```

And `CV_MAKETYPE` is:

```
#define CV_MAKETYPE(depth,cn) (CV_MAT_DEPTH(depth) + (((cn)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT))
```

where `cn` is the number of channels, and `CV_CN_SHIFT` is 3. I'm betting the type 16 you are seeing is actually

`(0 + ((3 - 1) << 3)) -> 16` or AKA `CV_8UC3`.

So, you have an 8bpp RGB image not a CV_AA image :)

You need to convert each channel from `CV_8U` to `CV_32F`.

**EDIT :** Take a look at using [cvSplit](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvsplit#void%20cvSplit%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst0,%20CvArr%2a%20dst1,%20CvArr%2a%20dst2,%20CvArr%2a%20dst3%29) and [cvMerge](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvmerge#void%20cvMerge%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src0,%20const%20CvArr%2a%20src1,%20const%20CvArr%2a%20src2,%20const%20CvArr%2a%20src3,%20CvArr%2a%20dst%29) (I haven't used the C interface in a while, but it should be something like the following):

```
IplImage* src = cvCreateImage( size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 ); // CV_8UC3
IplImage* r8u = cvClone(src); 
IplImage* g8u = cvClone(src);
IplImage* b8u = cvClone(src);

IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage( size, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3 ); // CV_32F
IplImage* r32f = cvClone(dst); 
IplImage* g32f = cvClone(dst);
IplImage* b32f = cvClone(dst);

// split the channels apart...
cvSplit(src, b8u, g8u, r8u, NULL); // assuming in OpenCV BGR order here...may be RGB...

// convert the data...
cvConvertScale(b8u, b32f, 1, 0);
cvConvertScale(g8u, g32f, 1, 0);
cvConvertScale(r8u, r32f, 1, 0);

// merge them back together again if you need to...
cvMerge(r32f, g32f, b32f, NULL, dst);
```

Comment: Ohhh I think you might be right.. But how do I convert each channel from CV_8U to CV_32F?

Comment: Your example doesn't quite work but I'm trying to massage it to make sense... I am reading in from an AVI file with cvCreateFileCapture, then copying the IplImage *frame into a CvMat object (which is what I need). Then trying to convert like you listed, but not having much luck..

Comment: @Chris Did you get it working? If not, could you update your answer with your code snippet, and I'll try to help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, to convert between types use [`cvConvertScale()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#convertscale) and set the `scale` param to **1** and `shift` to **0**.

A nice macro for this is:

```
#define cvConvert(src, dst)  cvConvertScale((src), (dst), 1, 0 )
```